# UIDocumentPicker can not display Browse at iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios11, uidocumentpickervc

I wrote a program of UIDocumentPicker.
However, if I tap "Browse" on the iOS 11 simulator, loading continues to be displayed and could not be displayed.
What kind of response is necessary?

#### Development environment

- Xcode: Version 9.0 beta 5
- Simulator: iPhone 7 Plus (iOS 11.0)

#### Error Image

[image]

#### Code

https://github.com/amarron1/SampleDocumentPicker

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIDocumentPickerDelegate {
    let UTIs:[String] = ["public.data"]
    // Save to this application from iCloud
    @IBAction func importDocumentPicker(_ sender: Any) {
        let importPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: self.UTIs, in: .import)
        importPicker.delegate = self
        present(importPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

#### Log

```
2017-09-06 11:37:54.790680+0900 SampleDocumentPicker[40282:5448334] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <_UIWaitingForRemoteViewContainerViewController: 0x7fb54c6153b0>.
2017-09-06 11:38:04.101520+0900 SampleDocumentPicker[40282:5448334] [DocumentManager] The view service did terminate with error: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={Message=Service Connection Interrupted}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of it, this is a simulator-only issue. (iOS 11.0 simulator)
UIDocumentPicker works ok on devices.

If anyone encounters this problem, just test on a real device.